# Carrierwave, MiniMagick, and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, minimagick

In my Rails app, I enable users to upload images using Carrierwave and Amazon S3.  I want to implement a feature that lets users edit existing images by rotating it 90 degrees.

I'm confused about where this code would go.  Does it go in the image uploader file, or the image controller?  And how is it called?  I believe it should look something like this:

```
image = Image.find(params[:id])
image_obj = MiniMagick::Image.read(image.file)
image_obj.rotate(-90)
image_obj.write(image.file)
```

But I haven't been able to find examples to help me.  If anyone can give me a pointer in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

**Edit**

Thanks to deep for their thorough response!  Here is what I ended up doing:

In my view:

```
# image.html.erb:
<%= link_to rotate_image_path(:id => image.id), :remote => true %>
```

In my controller:

```
# image_controller.rb:
def rotate
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @image.rotated = true
    @image.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :nothing => true }
    end
end
```

In my model:

```
  # image.rb
  attr_accessible :rotated
  after_save :rotate_image, if: ->(obj){obj.rotated.present? && obj.rotated?}

  def rotate_image
    self.image_path.recreate_versions!
  end
```

In my uploader:

```
  # image_uploader.rb
  process :rotate_img

  def rotate_img
  if model.rotated.present? && model.rotated?
      manipulate! do |img|
        img.rotate '-90'
        img
      end
  end
end
```

The only real change I made was in the uploader, where I ran into errors trying to do a condition process.  I put the conditional within the rotate_img method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my solution

First define a attribute accessor in your model and on update set it to true.

In your model

```
#image.rb
attr_accessor :rotate
```

In your controller

```
#images_controller.rb
def update
  @image = Image.find(params[:id])
  @image.rotate = true
  @image.save
  redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Bla bla bla"
end
```

Carrierwave provides a `recreate_versions!` method which will process and re-upload the image. In you case you can add a `after_save` callback that will trigger `recreate_versions!` method only if the rotate attribute is set to true.

In your model

```
#image.rb
after_save :rotate_image, if: ->(obj){ obj.rotate.present? and obj.rotate? }

def rotate_image
  self.file.recreate_versions!
end
```

Now in your image uploader you can write the code to rotate a image.

```
#image_uploader.rb
.......
# It will replace the original image with rotated version 
process :rotate_img, :if => model.rotate.present and model.rotate?

def rotate_img
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.rotate "90" 
    img #returns the manipulated image
  end
end
```

If you don't want to replace the original image then all you have to do is to call process inside a version like

```
# Create different versions of your uploaded files:
version :rotated_img do
  process :rotate_img
end
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the thorough response.  I will try this out and then mark the answer as correct if it works for me!